# Hiding column with Flex-Layout

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm just starting to work with Angular 2 and I have a project where I am using Material 2. I'm trying to create a responsive effect, where I hide a column when my screen is 960 or lower.

I know Material 2 has a way to detect column size for sizing, like the following:

```
gt-sm   '(min-width: 960px)'
```

Does anyone know of a way in Angular 2 and Material 2 to detect and hid a column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`fxShow`](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxShow-API) and [`fxhide`](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxHide-API).

You can use them like this:

```
<div fxHide fxShow.gt-sm></div>
```